# magento1.9 : Integarion violation database error in admin

Tags: magento-1.9

While updating bundle product in admin it is throwing error like SQL

```
   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'selection price type' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_bundle_selection_price` (`selection_id`,`website_id`,`selection_price_type`,`selection_price_value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `selection_price_type` = VALUES(`selection_price_type`), `selection_price_value` = VALUES(`selection_price_value`)
```

Help me